# Android MotionEvent data missing on Galaxy Tab II

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

**Background:**

I'm making a little test app on Android that just displays on screen all data the app can sense about all fingers touching the screen.  It is similar to [this one](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/04/detect-touch-event-part-iv-get-touch_12.html), but for all touches instead of just one.  Android touch events contain lots of data (as per [this doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)), including position, orientation, pressure, size, and ellipse axis lengths.

**Problem:**

Every MotionEvent my app receives reports 0 (zero) for getSize(i), getTouchMajor(i), and getTouchMinor(i) for every pointer index i.  But it reports sensible, nonzero position and pressure values, so something's working right.  The docs *seem to* suggest that this means the hardware does not support that information, but I'm skeptical about that for two reasons.

1. The device on which I'm testing is a Galaxy Tab II, which I thought was pretty fancy.  (I searched the web to see if I could find a list of features that various Android devices supported for MotionEvents, but failed to find such a list.)
2. I used the Java method InputDevice.getMotionRanges() to test whether the device supports size and major/minor axes, and those results suggest that the device *does* support those axes (I got size: 0.0-1.0, major/minor: 0.0-1509.437 each).

**Questions:**

1. Am I correct in concluding that a Galaxy Tab II supports the size and major/minor axis features of MotionEvent, and if so, why can't I get that data from actual MotionEvents?  (My code is very much like the code linked to above.)
2. If this tablet doesn't actually support those axes, can you recommend what Android tablet I *could* be doing this on that *would* give me MotionEvent sizes and ellipse axis lengths?

Thanks in advance for any help available!

**Edit:** Coworkers testing the app on a Galaxy Tab I get all the data, none missing.  Is there some configuration/setting difference we might have between the devices?  It seems very strange that the Galaxy Tab would downgrade from I to II...

Comment: I'm having same problem with galaxy tab 2.
Even developer option "pointer location" is reporting 0 for event size. Try using nexus 7, it is reporting correct values.

Comment: Am I understading this right? Through MotionEvent class, you are not able to use methods as getSize(), getTouchMajor(), getTouchMinor(), and getOrientation(). WHEN using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.
But you are able to do so using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 1?

My project group and I are looking for devices that supports these features. :)

Comment: Additionally I'm working with Kmulla from this Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050028/android-finger-detection-orientation-and-ellipse.
And we tried about 4 devices, including Nexus 7. No Luck. getOrientation() always 0, and getTouchMajor() = getTouchMinor(), and the axes were always the same.

Comment: This project was 18 months ago, and I no longer have access to the tablets in question.  The Galaxy Tab II was used by me, and the Galaxy Tab I by remote collaborators.  Therefore I did not personally verify that a Galaxy Tab I worked; I was only __told__ that it worked for others.  Do the `InputDevice.getMotionRanges()` methods help in your case at all?  (They did not for me, as mentioned above, but perhaps they will for you?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this on a similar question.
[onTouch MoitonEvent getTouchMinor and getTouchMajor alwasys the exact same number result, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032486/ontouch-moitonevent-gettouchminor-and-gettouchmajor-alwasys-the-exact-same-numbe/22065092#22065092)

In our findings we found no device that gave different major and minor lengths for an ellipse, or that could give an orientation of such an ellipse.

Most devices we tested only gave one value which, we believed to be the diagonal.